# Best way to update CF app, db and server code

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I've built a Compact Framework application to be used by delivery drivers. The system includes a WCF Service and SQL database on the server as well as a SQL CE database and CF application running on the mobile device.

Now the question is how to I update all this easily when I release new versions? The problems are:

- it may be deployed to hundreds of PDAs
- when first installed on a PDA the SQL CE database has to be populated. This can take a while. I don't want to have to do this each time the app is upgraded so I'm going to have to run scripts to update the db schema rather than just replacing the whole file and repopulating it.
- the WCF service code will need to be updated
- the SQL database schema will need to be updated

I can see solutions to all this but it seems like a lot of work. I thought it may be helpful to get a few tips before I launch into it all.

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 1):

I've done some projects with more or less the same requierements.

> it may be deployed to hundreds of PDAs

I'll recommend to use an updater, within the application. It checks via a webservice the availability of a new version. Download if theres an update. Then run another process to perform the update(This process I only use to run wceload.exe and then reboot the device).

> when first installed on a PDA the SQL CE database has to be populated. This can take a while. I don't want to have to do this each time the app is upgraded so I'm going to have to run scripts to update the db schema rather than just replacing the whole file and repopulating it.

Don't include your database as a file for the application, create the scripts and check if the db exists if not create the db.

> the WCF service code will need to be updated

I have an update webservice which is independent so the contract wont change. Which receives the current version, authentication and returns if the update is available and the url for the file to download.

You will need two different address to update and keep the other part working.Just perform a redirect in the new version.

> the SQL database schema will need to be updated

I hope you mean that you refer to the server backend so I recommend to use views to search for the information.

If you mean to the SQLCE db you can ship patching scripts or plain erase the db and recreate the db.